renaming jobId in spark UI during spark structured streaming
I was able to rename job description in SparkUI using setJobDescription , buy only my preprocessing data was renamed (cached dataset) , but the main job/stage isn't renamed
For exemple:
My cache stage:

But my stream job isn't renamed :

same thing inside my streaming job, at stage level:

is there a way to do it ?

I believe what you are looking for is to set the queryName property
sourceData.writeStream()
   .queryName(queryName)
   ...
   .start()
   .awaitTermination();

Give that a try.

This is not what I looking for, this give a name to a stream, I want to give name to jobs and stage inside a stream execution plan.
